# Hive: Parse nested json list

Tags: hive

I have data which comprises nested json list, like:

```
{"id":"aaa", "list":[{"eventId":222},{"details":[{"sub1":333},{"sub2":444}]},{"name":555}]}
```

The target is to extract the "outer" list, like

```
 id       data
aaa   {"eventId":222}
aaa   {"details":[{"sub1":333},{"sub2":444}]} 
aaa   {"name":555}
```

How to explode the `list` without split the inner nested json list? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the built in function [get_json_object](http://thornydev.blogspot.com/2013/07/querying-json-records-via-hive.html)  or `json_tupple` to get the json objects together with hive [posexplode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-posexplode) to retrieve values from list

For example,

```
SELECT get_json_object(json_object, $.id) as id,
       posexplode(get_json_object(json_object, $.list)) as pos, val
       FROM your table;
```

From that you can just use get_json_object on your pos,val columns.

You could also use `explode` with `lateral VIEW` on hive

Note

This SQL code was only for ilustrating, it may have some errors

edit:

As pointed by @leftjoin, would be impossible to handle this king with the return from get_json_object. Maybe se solution would be use a [udf](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins) to handle this case.

Comment: Are you aware that get_json_object returns string, not array? And posexplode needs array. And tricky part here is to split string in such way that nested elements are not splitted.

Comment: Maybe here the solution would be get_json_object for the list combined with a split function?

Comment: using third party functions. For example like this: https://github.com/munim15/Hive-JSON-Array-UDF or write your own

Comment: it is difficult to split array correctly in this case. if splitting by comma between } and { - it will not work. need to split by comma between } and { excluding nested structures, extremely difficult if ever possible to write such regexp in split

Comment: Yep, I think the easier solution would be using UDF for hive, or use spark to do this transformation (I don't know if he use spark on his hadoop cluster here)